# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException ERROR - Database android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I know its repeated question but none of the solutions are working for me.

I am new to sql database. I am practicing example from the site tutorialpoint. Example [Link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)
I am getting .CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0 error on deleting the name from the database. So if I add 4 name name in the database and start deleting the first name, it get deleted and then clicking on the second name it gives me this error ( .CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0). And then if i click on third name I am able to delete the name but same error for the fourth name.
I want user can delete any row from the database or can delete the entire row

ERROR

```
02-22 20:53:59.546 6148-6148/com.xxxx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xx.x.Activity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:400)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
    at com.solution.tracking.forklift.DetailsActivity.onCreate(xxxjava:47)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
```

DB

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDBName.db";
public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "contacts";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID = "id";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME = "name";

private HashMap hp;

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "create table contacts " +
                    "(id integer primary key, name text)"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean insertContact(String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);

    db.insert("contacts", null, contentValues);
    return true;
}

public Cursor getData(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts where id="+id+"", null );
    return res;
}

public int numberOfRows(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    int numRows = (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
}

public boolean updateContact(Integer id, String name) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("name", name);

    db.update("contacts", contentValues, "id = ? ", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) } );
    return true;
}

public Integer deleteContact (Integer id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("contacts",
            "id = ? ",
            new String[] { Integer.toString(id) });
}

public ArrayList<String> getAllCotacts() {
    ArrayList<String> array_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    //hp = new HashMap();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor res =  db.rawQuery( "select * from contacts", null );
    res.moveToFirst();

    while(res.isAfterLast() == false){
        array_list.add(res.getString(res.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME)));
        res.moveToNext();
    }
    return array_list;
}
```

devicedetailsActivity

```
public class devicedetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "MESSAGE";
private ListView obj;
DBHelper mydb;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.devicedetails_layout);
    FullScreencall();
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllCotacts();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.simple_list_item_1, array_list);

    obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    obj.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int id_To_Search = arg2 + 1;

            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", id_To_Search);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailsActivity.class);

            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
public void FullScreencall() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { // lower api


        int mUIFlag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;


        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);

    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        //for new api versions.
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;

        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.home, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.item1:Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", 0);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);

            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.item2: dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", 0);
             intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);

            startActivity(intent);
            return true;


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public boolean onKeyDown(int keycode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keycode, event);
}
```

DetailsActivity

```
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int from_Where_I_Am_Coming = 0;
private DBHelper mydb ;

TextView name ;

int id_To_Update = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.details);
    FullScreencall();
    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);


    mydb = new DBHelper(this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");

        if(Value>0){
            //means this is the view part not the add contact part.
            Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
            id_To_Update = Value;
            rs.moveToFirst();
            String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
            if (!rs.isClosed())  {
                rs.close();
            }
            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            name.setText((CharSequence)nam);
            name.setFocusable(false);
            name.setClickable(false);
        }
    }
}
public void FullScreencall() {
    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 11 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) { // lower api


        int mUIFlag = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;


        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(mUIFlag);

    } else if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
        //for new api versions.
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;

        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras !=null) {
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");
        if(Value>0){
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.display_contact, menu);
        } else{
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.back, menu);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Edit_Contact:
            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            name.setEnabled(true);
            name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            name.setClickable(true);


            return true;
        case R.id.Delete_Contact:

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteContact)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),devicedetailsActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });

            AlertDialog d = builder.create();
            d.setTitle("Are you sure");
            d.show();

            return true;
        case R.id.back:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),devicedetailsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return  true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}

public void run(View view) {
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");
        if(Value>0){
            if(mydb.updateContact(id_To_Update,name.getText().toString()
                    )){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),devicedetailsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else{
            if(mydb.insertContact(name.getText().toString())){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "done",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not done",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),devicedetailsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the return value of [Cursor#moveToFirst](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()), the documentation says that moveToFirst return false if the cursor is empty.

```
if(extras !=null) {
    int Value = extras.getInt("id");

    if(Value>0){
        //means this is the view part not the add contact part.
        Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
        if(rs.moveToFirst()) {
            id_To_Update = Value;
            rs.moveToFirst();
            String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
            Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            name.setText((CharSequence)nam);
            name.setFocusable(false);
            name.setClickable(false);
        }
        if (!rs.isClosed())  {
            rs.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if I add 4 name in the database and start deleting the first name, it get deleted and then clicking on the second name it taking me to Add screen. And then if i click on third name I am able to delete the name but same taking me the add screen for the fourth name. - But using your code it is not throwing me the CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException ERROR

Comment: As i understand your list is not beign updated when you delete a contact, that's because anytime you make a change in the table you need to update the cursor (notify the cursor in some way that the data has change) see [Cursor#setNotificationUri](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#setNotificationUri(android.content.ContentResolver,%20android.net.Uri)). Another Way to do it it's calling by result the DetailsActivity and in setResult say if an operation was made

Answer (score 1):

This error means you are not getting any data from the data base and you are trying to access some value.

In order to avoid the error check if the Cursor has some data.

```
name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    mydb = new DBHelper(this);
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras !=null) {
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");
        if(Value>0){
            //means this is the view part not the add contact part.
            Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
            //Check if cursor has value
            if(rs != null && rs.getCount() > 0){  
              id_To_Update = Value;
              rs.moveToFirst();
              String nam = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_NAME));
              if (!rs.isClosed())  {
                  rs.close();
              } 
              Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
              b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

              name.setText((CharSequence)nam);
              name.setFocusable(false);
              name.setClickable(false);
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I did exactly same what u did here but the problem I am facing here is when I delete the first row it successful get deleted . After deleting the first row and try to delete second one the value is not showing up  in text view name.setText((CharSequence)nam) and I am not able to delete it. But it is triggering successful deleted. I updated my complete code.

Comment: user can delete entire row or can delete any name from this list and show nothing in screen.

Comment: I don't see the code that delete any data from the data base. Can you post it please?

Comment: I update my entire code. So user can delete all contact or can delete any contact from the list. I am able to delete question but not all the questions.

Comment: Just add related code. Remove all unnecessary code and show where you call the method `deleteContact` or when you're getting the error.

Comment: I updated my DetailsActivity. I am calling deleteContact method in DetailActivity

Comment: I guess I found out the exact problem. So if I add 4 name name in the database and start deleting the first name, it get deleted and then clicking on the second name it gives me this error ( .CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0). And then if i click on third name I am able to delete the name but same error for the fourth name. NOTE: this is without using your code.